# Alternatives to the Visitor Pattern With Better Return

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I was following an LLVM tutorial. During the code generation phase, they just used virtual functions to implement codegen functions. But, they said something like a visitor pattern would be useful – to decouple expression objects with all the algorithms that will be run on them.

The problem is that visitor patterns don't easily allow for return. After browsing the web for quite a while, I found all the solutions very, very clunky.

Additionally, I can't just create a CodeGen class and pass in the expression, because our expressions are all derived from a base expression class. The call would have to be made from within the expression in order to get the correct type.

I can't think of a nice way to do this. Can anybody tell me what sort of patterns I should be looking at? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Strategy or Template Method pattern?

Comment: If you can't use visitor because you cannot touch the existing inheritance tree, than your client code shouldn't depend on this base types but on a wrapper type. You could wrap the expressions in a type that allows you to extend it with all required features. The wrapper delegates operations to the inner expression type. Like a decorator or adapter. To me its difficult to understand why you can't use visitor here.

Comment: What about using [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/variant.html)?  The library has a `static_visitor` that can return values when visiting.